# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'compute_mark_list' Python

Tags: python, xml

I got a error message in Python:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'compute_mark_list'
```

in my code.

This code suppose to read though a XML file and get the content inside its children:

```
import libxml2
import sys

'''
purpose
    store the information from an answer element
'''
class Answer:
    def __init__(self, index, path, result, answer, time):
        self.index = index
        self.path = path
        self.result = result
        self.answer = answer
        self.time = time

'''
purpose
    Store the information from a display element.
'''
class Display:
    def __init__(self, index, path, time):
        self.index = index
        self.path = path
        self.time = time

'''
purpose
    Extract the information from log_file and return it as a list
    of answer and display objects.
preconditions
    log_file is the name of a legal, readable quiz log XML file
'''
def load_quiz_log(log_file):
    # parse the XML file in argv[2] and load it into memory
    parse_tree = libxml2.parseFile(sys.argv[1])

    # create a context for tree traversal
    context = parse_tree.xpathNewContext()

    root = parse_tree.getRootElement()

    log_file = root.children

    #create a list to hold the objects  
    L = [ ]

    while log_file is not None:
        if log_file.name == 'answer':
            answer = log_file.content
        if log_file.name == 'display':
            display = log_file.content
        log_file = log_file.next

    L = [answer, display]

    return L

'''
purpose
    Return the number of distinct questions in log_list.
preconditions
    log_list was returned by load_quiz_log
'''
def compute_question_count(log_list):
    while log_list is not None:
        if log_list.name == 'answer':
            count +=  1
        else:
            break   
    log_list = log_list.next
    return count

'''
purpose
    Extract the list of marks.
    For each index value, use the result from the last non-empty answer,
    or 0 if there are no non-empty results.
preconditions
    log_list was returned by load_quiz_log
'''
def compute_mark_list(log_list):
    marks = [ ]
    while log_list is not None:
        if log_list.name == 'answer':
            log_list_answer = log_list.children
            while log_list_answer is not None:
                if log_list_answer.name == 'index':
                    index = 0
                    if log_list_answer.content == index:
                        result = log_list_answer.next.next.content
                        index = log_list_answer.content 
                        marks.append(result)                    
                    else:
                        continue
            log_list_answer = log_list_answer.next
    log_list = log_list.next
    return marks
```

When I run this code I get the error message in the title

```
import libxml2
import sys
import quiz_library

print '-------------------- test load_quiz_log'

log_list = quiz_library.load_quiz_log(sys.argv[1])

for x in log_list:
    if isinstance(x, quiz_library.Answer):
        print 'Answer:', x.index, x.path, x.result, x.answer, x.time
    else:
        print 'Display:', x.index, x.path, x.time

print '-------------------- test compute_question_count'

question_count = quiz_library.compute_question_count(log_list)
print question_count

print '-------------------- test compute_mark_list'

mark_list = quiz_library.compute_mark_list(log_list)
print mark_list
```

The XML file looks like:

[image]

Comment: Something is setting `quiz_library` to a string, instead of the module that you define with `import`.

Comment: A full traceback would be helpful.